# Failed insert in db by ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have trouble with inserting in psql db by ef core method ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync/ExecuteSqlInterpolated.
TableScheme:

```
      Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 Id       | integer |           | not null | nextval('"LookupRows_Id_seq"'::regclass)
 Index    | integer |           | not null | 
 RowData  | text    |           | not null | 
 LookupId | integer |           | not null |
```

Insert method:

```
FormattableString str = $"INSERT into \"LookupRows\" (\"Index\", \"RowData\", \"LookupId\") VALUES {q.First()};";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(str.ToString(),cancellationToken);
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"INSERT into \"LookupRows\" (\"Index\", \"RowData\", \"LookupId\") VALUES {q.First()};",cancellationToken);

q.First() = (0, '{{"0":["0","Bucharest","0"]}}', 115)
```

ExecuteSqlRawAsync works fine. Entry successfully insert.
But ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync always return an error:
`MessageText: syntax error at or near "$1"`
I ran out of ideas. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRawAsync works fine.` not the way you used it. Neither option works. In the first case the code is using plain old string manipulation to construct a SQL query, allowing SQL injection and conversion errors. In the second case the syntax is simply invalid - instead of supplying a parameter name surrounded by `{}`, a value is used

Comment: What is `q` what does `q.First()` return? What are this object's properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos q - is a IEnumerable<string>. I want to join it with "," and insert in db.
q.First() is just first element in this collection.
q.First() returns this - (0, '{{"0":["0","Bucharest","0"]}}', 115)

Comment: This won't work and is fully vulnerable to SQL injection. `VALUES` requires a separate parameter for each column value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your answer. I think i understood my mistake. Is there a way to join parameters from IEnumerable and insert it in db by 1 query? Without injections risks, of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither option works.

In the first case the code is using plain old string manipulation to construct a SQL query, allowing SQL injection and conversion errors. If that `q.First()` is a string whose value is `('','',''); drop table Users;--`, you'd end up with a dropped table.

In the second case the syntax is simply invalid. Instead of supplying the 3 values expected through parameters, a single value is used.

The *correct* syntax for `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` is :

```
var sql=@"INSERT into LookupRows (Index, RowData, LookupId) 
VALUES (@index,@row,@lookup);"

var paramObject=new {index=1,row="abc",lookup=100};
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, paramObject, cancellationToken);
```

The parameter object's properties must match the parameter names.

The correct syntax for `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` is:

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
    @$"INSERT into LookupRows (Index, RowData, LookupId) 
VALUES ({paramObject.index},{paramObject.row},{paramObject.lookup});", 
cancellationToken);
```

or

```
FormattableString sql=@$"INSERT into LookupRows (Index, RowData, LookupId) 
VALUES ({paramObject.index},{paramObject.row},{paramOject.lookup});";

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(sql, cancellationToken);
```

`ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` will inspect the FormattableString and generate a new parameterized query using the string placeholders as positional parameters and their values as parameter values. It's the equivalent of:

```
var sql=@"INSERT into LookupRows (Index, RowData, LookupId) 
VALUES (?,?,?);"

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, 1,"abc",100);
```

Using `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` is rather risky because it's *way* too easy to forget to explicitly specify `FormattableString` and end up with :

```
var sql=@$"INSERT into LookupRows (Index, RowData, LookupId) 
VALUES ({paramObject.index},{paramObject.row},{paramObject.lookup});";
```

Which is just a string constructed from data, and once again vulnerable to SQL injection

**Inserting 100K items**

Looks like the actual problem is inserting 100K rows. ORMs are the wrong tool for this job. In this case, instead of a single graph of objects there are 100K rows with no business logic.

Executing 100K INSERT statements will take a long time and flood the database's transaction log. The solution is to use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to insert the rows using bulk operations and minimal logging.

[SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) expects a DataTable or DataReader. To use an `IEnumerable<T>` we can use [FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) to wrap it:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> data = ... 


using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) ;
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "Id", "Name", "Description")) 
{ 
  bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
  bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

**Importing CSVs**

To import CSV files one can use CsvHelper's [CsvDataReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) :

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {       
           
      bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
      bcp.WriteToServer(dr); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Insert multiple rows at once? T-SQL doesn't have arrays and even if it did, they wouldn't work with `VALUES`. Why not allow EF Core itself to insert the rows? If `LookupRows` is mapped to an entity, you can add all the items you want to it then call `SaveChanges`. EF Core will generate the INSERT statements to insert all of the values in a single transaction

Comment: SaveChanges, unfortunately is very slow. I need to insert over 100k entries and it lasts like eternity if i use SaveChanges().

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin so is what you try to do now. `SaveChanges` doesn't do something special, it executes `INSERTs`. If you want to insert 100K items you need SqlBulkCopy, not EF Core. There are no objects in your case, just rows. That's not what you asked though

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin where does the data come from?

Comment: this rows insert is part of big transaction which inserting entity of Lookup. Lookup and his headers is relatively small and saveChanges for them is ok. I try to insert LookupRows in the same transaction, in case of something happend. I'll try to use SqlBulkCopy. Thank you for your help

Comment: data come from file. Upload by users. Protection from SQL Inj is necessary, unfortunately.

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin no it's not and I just posted how to load any `IEnumerable<T>` using SqlBulkCopy. Again, what is the source? A JSON file? CSV? Excel file? Some libraries like CsvHelpler or ExcelDataReader already provide a DbDataReader that can be used with SqlBulkCopy. In other cases you can use `ObjectReader`

Comment: the source is parsed csv file with separators

Comment: If you use CsvHelper's CsvDataReader you can avoid loading all the parsed rows into memory. I added how to use that as well

Comment: look into SqlBulkCopy as you suggested. It is really good solution, but my db is postgresql

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin you should probably post a question asking what you *really* want. Insert 100K rows from a CSV file into PostgreSQL using C#. Assuming you use NpgSQL [you can use COPY](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) and even insert CSV data directly